# Economics Math: Optimal allocation of free time from Core Econ website. MRT = MRS

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fractions, economics

**CONTEXT**:
I have the following equation for MRT=MRS  (marginal rate of transformation = marginal rate of substitution):
$\frac{αy}{24-t} = \frac{ay}{bt}$
I am asked to "multiply through" by $\frac{t}{y}$, which gives the following result:
$\frac{αt}{24-t} = \frac{a}{b}$

The "multiplying through by $\frac{t}{y}$" is what seems to be confusing me.

**QUESTION**
Can anyone show me the individual steps that get from  $\frac{αy}{24-t} = \frac{ay}{bt}$ to the result $\frac{αt}{24-t} = \frac{a}{b}$?

Comment: What is meant is that both sides of the equation **has been multiplied by** $\frac{t}y$: $$\frac{t}y\cdot \frac{αy}{24-t} = \frac{t}y\cdot \frac{ay}{bt}$$ On the LHS you can cancel $y$ and on the RHS you can cancel $y$ and $t$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: You´re welcome.